# Passing data into @Input() of a dynamically generated component works in stackblitz but not on my own computer

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm dynamically creating a component in Angular 13 with `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` like so

```
const componentInstance : ComponentRef<unknown> = this.vcRef.createComponent(YourComponent);
```

There's instances where I want to pass data into the component before embedding it into the view which at first I couldn't figure out how to do but when making [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kncrsb?file=src/app/responsive-frame/responsive-frame.component.ts) to highlight the problem I wound up coming up with a solution by doing this

```
componentInstance.instance['PropName'] = 'some value';
```

On my computer however it won't compile because I get an `Object is of type unknown` error.  Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Probably because of ComponentRef<unknown>? Try to replace with any or with the actual component type.

Comment: THAT WORKED!!! thanks.  If you make that into an actual answer I'd be more than happy to select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since **v14.1.0**, Angular added the `setInput()` method to the component reference:

Sharing this elegant solution from [this article](https://netbasal.com/a-new-way-to-set-inputs-on-angular-componentrefs-6214f95db63d):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[container]',
})
export class ContainerDirective {
  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const ref = this.vcr.createComponent(FooComponent);
    ref.setInput('text', 'Angular');
    ref.setInput('myAlias', 'v14.1.0');
    // This will throw an error
    ref.setInput('doesNotExist', 'error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you assign a `YourComponent` type to `unknown` type like below:

```
const componentInstance : ComponentRef<unknown> = this.vcRef.createComponent(YourComponent);
```

Then try to access the property:

```
componentInstance.instance['PropName'] = 'some value';
```

---

#### Solution 1

To resolve that, you first need to type guard the `unknown` type before using it:

```
if(componentInstance instanceof YourComponent)
  componentInstance.instance['PropName'] = 'some value';
```

And that's basically `unknown` is used for. It's used when we don't know type beforehand. Then we have a bunch of `type guard` to funnel it to the right type before we call its functions/properties.

example:

```
function print(x: unknown) {

  if(typeof x === 'string')
    return 'x is string';
  
  if(x instanceof YourComponent)
    return x.name;
}
```

#### Solution 2

Another solution is to give the actual type during the assignment:

```
const componentInstance : ComponentRef<YourComponent> = this.vcRef.createComponent(YourComponent);
```

#### Solution 3

OR not giving any explicit type at all since TypeScript can infer the type from the left hand side of the assignment:

```
const componentInstance = this.vcRef.createComponent(YourComponent);
```